# One domain, one codebase, unlimited sub-domains and databases

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to host a marketing site and a demo app using GAE.

http://mysite.com => Marketing site
http://demo.mysite.com => Demo site

http://client.mysite.com => Client site
...

Each time a client signs up I need to be able to dynamically add a datastore for said client.

Is this something doable using GAE??? Do the Cloud SQL instances have an API I can call to add a DB and beging installing a client account???

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

You can set up `*.mysite.com` to point to your app, by setting your CNAME records accordingly.  See [App Engine's Using a Custom Domain documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain) for details on how to set this up properly.

Then, within your servlet/request handler, filter the domain in the request URI to find out what the subdomain is.  After that, many of the services (datastore, memcache, etc.) have "multitenancy" support, where you can specify what namespace you're doing operations in.  You can set that to the subdomain.

I don't know what language you're using, but here are the docs for multitenancy:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/multitenancy/multitenancy
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy

Comment: It might be useful to mention that you can use a wildcard when setting up the CNAME record for your domain, so you can set that to `*.mydomain.com`

Comment: Good suggestion.  I've edited in a link to App Engine's documentation on how to set this up.